# Fetching results using AJAX with Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am working with Wordpress and I have made a page (`dm_page.php`) that uses the *Contact form 7* plugin in which I created the dropdown list. On change event of dropdown list, I am hitting ajax. The code for ajax I wrote in the `header.php`. The file to which ajax is giving the data is `getdata.php`, placed in theme folder.

**getdata.php:**

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$ddlval = $_POST['ddlval'];
$results = $wpdb->get_row('select * from my_dynamictest where lang="'.$ddlval.'"', ARRAY_A);

$someArray = [];
array_push($someArray,[
    'id' => $results['id'],
    'name' => $results['name']
]);

echo json_encode($someArray);
?>
```

This is the error I am getting:

> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function get_row() on null in...

I am not able to figure this out what the error says. Please help. Consider me as total beginner in Wordpress.

Comment: Is this the total code for this page?

Answer (score 0):

I am going on the assumption that what you have provided is the total of the code for this AJAX page. If so, (there may be an *"official"* way to do the AJAX call) but I just include the `wp-config.php` file:

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST))
    exit;
// If file in the themes folder: /wp-content/themes/dm_page.php: /../../wp-config.php
// If file inside a theme in the theme folder: /wp-content/themes/mytheme/dm_page.php: /../../../wp-config.php
require(__DIR__.'/../../../wp-config.php');
global $wpdb; 
$ddlval  =  $_POST['ddlval'];
$results =  $wpdb->get_row('select * from my_dynamictest where lang="'.$ddlval.'"', ARRAY_A);

$someArray = [];
array_push($someArray,[
    'id' => $results['id'],
    'name' => $results['name']
]);

echo json_encode($someArray);
?>
```

---

**EDIT**

Here are some apparently "official" ways to add ajax:

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/implement-ajax-wordpress-themes/

Answer (score 0):

You have to load `require(__DIR__.'/../../../wp-load.php');` at the starting of your file.

So your **getdata.php:** looks like below:

```
<?php
require(__DIR__.'/../../../wp-load.php');
global $wpdb;

$ddlval = $_POST['ddlval'];
$results = $wpdb->get_row('select * from my_dynamictest where lang="'.$ddlval.'"', ARRAY_A);

$someArray = [];
array_push($someArray,[
    'id' => $results['id'],
    'name' => $results['name']
]);

echo json_encode($someArray);
?>
```